# Exponential and poisson distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ have an exponential distribution with mean $\theta =2$ and let the conditional distribution of $(Y|X=x)$ have a Poisson distribution with mean $x$.

a) Find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

b) What is the marginal density of $Y$?

c) Find $P(Y=0)$ and $P(Y<=2)$.

So $X$ has $exp(\theta=2)$ which means $f(x)=(1/\theta)e^(-x/\theta)=(1/2)e^(-x/2)$ because $\theta=2$and $f(Y|X=x)=(\lambda^x e^(-\lambda))/x!=(x^x e^(-x))/x!$ because $\lambda=x$.

but from there I get stuck on just what to do with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting confused because of sloppy notation.

Capital letters denote random variables.  Lowercase letters denote realizations of a random variable.

So, the density of $X$ is correct:  $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x/2}, \quad x > 0.$$  The **conditional** probability mass function of $Y$, given $X = x$, is $$\Pr[Y = y \mid X = x] = e^{-x} \frac{x^y}{y!}, \quad y = 0, 1, 2, \ldots;$$ that is, $Y \mid X = x$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda = x$.

Therefore, the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \Pr[Y = y \mid X = x] f_X(x),$$ for a suitably chosen support of $X$ and $Y$.  Note that this joint distribution is continuous for $X$ but discrete for $Y$.

The marginal (unconditional) probability mass function of $Y$ is given by $$\Pr[Y = y] = \int_{x=0}^\infty \Pr[Y = y \mid X = x] f_X(x) \, dx.$$  That is to say, it is the integral of the joint distribution over $x$.

The rest is straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I didn't want to respond until I worked through it all, to make sure I didn't get confused.